# Word: How to link data from Excel (as plaintext)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I have Excel table with some data and want this data to be linked in Word.  BUT only data (no-formatting).

So embeding an Excel object doen't work for me.

Thank you for suggestions!

### Example Excel table

[image]
(Excel table)

### Desired output

[image]
(as table)

or

[image]
(as plaintext with tabxs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, copy the data you want, e.g. using ctrl-C.

In Word, Use *Home->Paste->Paste Special*.

Check the Paste Link radio button, then select *Unformattted Unicode Text* as the format, and click *OK*.

Word pastes a *Link* to the data you selected. For text links, you should always be able to see what the link refers to by using Alt-F9 to reveal the field code, which might look something like this:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "c:\\mysheets\\xyz.xlsx" "Sheet1!R1C1:R2C3" \a \t \u }
```

Depending on your system setup, when you modify the data in R1C1:R2C3 in the sheet, Word may update the link automatically. If not, you should be able to update the data by selecting that field code and pressing F9 to update the field.

However, Word, will not modify a range such as R1C1:R2C3 automatically if you insert rows and columns in Excel. If you want to reference an area whose size may change, it is better to create a named range in Excel and reference that in the field code (which you can modify manually).

In more recent versions of Word, if you Paste Special->Paste Link using a graphical format, Word tends to "hide" the link code so it is not so easy to modify manually. But since you are looking for a text format, that should not be a problem.

Special, check the Paste Link option, then select one of the text options (I would suggest Unicode Text).

If you do that, then you have a Linked object in Word. When you modify the data in Excel, you can "update the link" (in fact that may happen automatically depending on your set-up and choices).

Comment: Nice, thank you. Is possible to use named table as named range? I tried to replace `RxCx:RyCy` with `Table1[#All]` (with and without keeping `Sheet1!` before), but it breakes the link.

Comment: @Lluser, Unfortunately, you cannot use the name actually created by Excel (either `Table1` or `Table1[#All])`. But if you select the table and create a new name, say Table1X that "refers To" `=Table1[#All]` , you *can* use `Sheet1!Table1X` . I'm not sure that has always been possible, so you should double-check.